# Angular 2 with Jade Template

Tags: angular, pug, server-side-rendering

I have a big web application developed using the following techonologies:

- webserver: Node.js + Express
- template engine: Jade
- css engine: less
- client side framework: AngularJS (v. 1.x)
- database: MongoDB

I'm very interested to switch to Angular 2 and use Angular 2 Universal in order to take advantages of Server Side Rendering.

Since I started the project using John Papa's style guide, (in theory) the upgrade to Angular 2 will be not a big trouble.

The problem that I have not resolved right now is using Jade inside Component template of Angular 2.

Example:

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'todo-app',
  template: `
    <h2>Todo</h2>
    <span>{{remaining}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span>
    [ <a href="javascript: false" (click)="archive()">archive</a> ]
    <todo-list [todos]="todos"></todo-list>
    <todo-form (newTask)="addTask($event)"></todo-form>`,
  directives: [TodoList, TodoForm]
})
```

I would like to put Jade instead html inside the template.

Do you have any advice on this? Someone of you have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

With Webpack [raw-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-loader) and [jade-html-loader](https://github.com/bline/jade-html-loader) loader:

```
loaders: [
  { test: /\.jade$/, loader: 'raw!jade-html' },
  // ...
]
```

you can do:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'todo-app',
  template: require('./todo-app.jade'),
  directives: [TodoList, TodoForm]
})
```

Comment: When using Jade you should note that http://html2jade.org/ is lowering case of attributes, see https://github.com/donpark/html2jade/issues/102 and WebStorm Jade parser does not work with angular2 syntax https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19625

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: '/path/to/your/template`
)}
```

That should read your template and if you transpile it to HTML there should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

I added a route to express that looks for partials and then renders the response. This gets express to use the render engine instead of just responding with the jade file. Note: I am using body-parser to get to the individual template file requested in the params of the request.

Here is my component definition:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [CoffeeShopsComponent],
  templateUrl: '/partials/app.component.jade'
})
```

Here is my express route definition:

```
app.get('/partials/*', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params);
  res.render('../partials/' + req.params[0]);
});
```

Replace '../partials/' with the path to your partials directory relative to the views directory.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong but, even when I found this answer super cool and I will use this aproach for sure, still we have the follow issue, for instance, if you want to implement an ngFor or an ngModel inside the template it is not going to be posible this way ritgth? or at least it is not shown in the code snipet how to achive such a goal...

Comment: *ngFor or ngModel will be left in the template by the the jade compiler. Then angular will see the ngFor and replicate the html.

Answer (score 0):

tomaszbak has the answer that works for Webpack.

If you're using a build tool like Gulp, then you're probably compiling things down into a build directory of some sort(something like a `www` or `app` folder). If that's the case, you can specify the path of the compiled template in the `templateUrl` portion of the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: 'app/templates/app.html'
})
```